# How to assign '1/1/1900' as default column value in VS2012 properties window

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012

The SQL server is set up to add '1/1/1900' as the default value to column `opendate`, `closedate` & `renwdate`.

The data entry screen has no place for these fields so they are updated internally by SQL as of now, but when I try to save the data error message that null value is not allowed is displayed.

If I turn the field to string type and assign '1/1/1900' it gives error cannot convert string to required format

[image: Screenshot of data layout & properties]

Comment: Please use interpunction. Your question is illegible.

Comment: @BartFriederichs I'm a native speaker, and I had to Google what the word *interpunction* means...

Comment: You can declare the column as "NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT", and set the default as "01/01/1900". In this manner, when the value of the column is NULL, or it's not filled, the system will set it to the default value.

Comment: how to do this in properties window of VS IDE

Comment: Why are your DateTime columns defined as String types?

Comment: @BerndLinde
Tried all option
The DefaultValue properties does not accept anything for datetime datatype except <DBNull>

Comment: It's not true. I tested it in my SQL Server 2008 environment, and it worked. You have to declare the column as datetime, not null, and fill the default field as '01/01/1900'. Then, when you issue an INSERT statement, you must specify '' (empty string) as the value of the column. This makes the system to insert the default value.

Comment: As Sergio did, I just tested on SQL Server 2012 with VS2012 and entering a default value for a DateTime column worked.

Comment: @SergioInternicola 
Achieved this by editing the file gslabdataDataSet.Designer.cs
and adding the line
this.columnopendate.DefaultValue = new System.DateTime(1900, 1, 1);

Comment: @BerndLinde what were the setting in the properties window
I did achieve that by changing the code (by hook or crook)

Comment: @user2035041 if i'm not mistaken there is a comment on the beginning of the file. something like the designer owns this one and regenerates it at will.

Comment: @Aツ
yes if the code is regenerated its lost and I have the same problem again
how to achieve this from properties window

Comment: @user2035041Screengrab of column properties: http://imgur.com/cgqsqUw Please note that my computer locale is set to Germany, hence the different display value of the DefaultValue column, but I did enter the value as "01/01/1900"

Comment: Thank You
@BerndLinde yes it worked 
I was trying to enter the string new System.DateTime(1900,1,1) in default value

Comment: @BerndLinde and what will be default value for UniqueIdentifier or GUID column if it will be generated by SQL server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
typeof(DateTime)
    .GetField ("MinValue")
    .SetValue (typeof(DateTime), new DateTime(1900, 1, 1));
```

Comment: how to do that in properties window?